# Change address of a passed pointer as function argument inside function in C

Tags: c, pointers

There is a function which has two pointers as input argument and there are a pointer and a array defined outside of the function. I want to write a function which changes address of the pointer outside of the function to the array.

```
void func(int8_t *pointer, char* array)
{
    pointer = array;
}

int main()
{

int8_t *pX;
char arr[100];

func(pX,arr);
```

The above code doesn't work because it only changes address of local pointers inside the function not the passed arguments.

Comment: `void func(int8_t **pointer, char* array)
{
    *pointer = (int8_t *)array; }`

Comment: Thanks, but the reason I asked this question was I could not find the answer as the subject of the that answer was "How to change value of variable passed as argument?" which does not represent a pointer passed as arguemtn.

Comment: you just need a pointer on the pointer. Check my comment, it solves your issue

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, yes, already did.

Comment: the accepted answer of the original question is exactly your case